# How do I filter english tweets only in snscrape?

Tags: python

This is the code I'm working with and it works fine and display all the 400 tweets I need in a csv file but my issue is that it adds other languages in the data so it makes it harder to use in a report. Any way I could filter in just english language only?

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd


query = "Cyberpunk"
tweets = []
limit = 400


for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():

    if len(tweets) == limit:
        break
    else:
        tweets.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.content])

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['Date', 'User', 'Tweet'])

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

[fasttext](https://pypi.org/project/fasttext/) is pretty fast:

```
#install fasttext and download the model
!pip install fasttext
!wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/supervised-models/lid.176.ftz
```

Example code with dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import fasttext

fmodel = fasttext.load_model('lid.176.ftz')

df = pd.DataFrame(['hello this is a great tweet', 'bonjour c\'est un super tweet', 'hallo, dit is een geweldige tweet'], columns=['tweet'])
df['language'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: fmodel.predict([x])[0][0][0].split('__label__')[1]) # detect tweet language
df = df[df['language'] == 'en'] # filter by language
```

output:

|  | tweet | language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | hello this is a great tweet | en |

Answer (score 0):

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd


query = "Cyberpunk"
tweets = []
limit = 400


for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():

    if len(tweets) == limit:
        break
    else:
        if tweet.lang=='en':
            tweets.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.content])

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['Date', 'User', 'Tweet'])

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).